# Does sprinkler control wire entering the house need to be grounded?

Tags: grounding, sprinkler-system

I'm installing a sprinkler controller in my basement.  I will be running control wires and sensor wire from the outdoor valves into the house.  Does these cables need to be grounded?  If so, how?

Details:

- Sprinkler valves: 24VAC
- Rain sensor: 5VDC
- Buried cables will enter PVC conduit to rise above top of foundation and into the house

Comment: Use whatever grounding comes with the low-voltage DC side of things. At some point, there will be a transformer that plugs into a standard 120v AC wall outlet. I'm willing to bet that the plug has a grounding pin on it and that should definitely be used. It should also be plugged into a GFCI protected outlet.

Comment: The cable is plastic and the wires in it each have a prescribed connection point at both ends.  There is nothing additional to "ground".  The valve neutral may be grounded in the controller.  Probably not and you shouldn't change it.  What is your worry?

Comment: @jay613, no particular worry, other than code compliance

Comment: BTW, I'm thinking about this because I noticed coax from the utility pole is grounded where in enters the house.  How is it determined which low-voltage cables need to be grounded?

Comment: Based on need and experience. 
 Grounding of utility cables from poles is related to lightning, and for coax also to noise reduction.  Neither is an issue with low voltage underground sprinkler cable.

Comment: Depending on your location, the wiring may have to meet a standard. See “Extra low voltage”

Answer (score 2):

No, the low-volt sprinkler cable does not need to be grounded.  Consider it similar to the thermostat wiring in an HVAC system.  They are isolated from the AC power distribution by a transformer.

Even through they carry a small amount of energy, they only provide the signal to engage a solenoid that allows the real work to be done by water pressure.